# C# List of arrays to array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to C#.  I am writing a program in which a list changes size depending on user input.  The list is of GPS coordinates so it is

```
List<double[]> coordinates= new List<double[]>();
```

However I  have a function that needs the GPS coordinates in `double[][]` format, an array of arrays.  It seems like this would be very straightforward because it seems like a list of arrays is already an array of arrays.  However, the most logical thing I can think to do fails:

```
double[][]test = new double[][]{};

test = coordinates.ToArray;
```

with "Cannot convert method group 'ToArray' to non-delegate type 'double[][]'. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Not sure what that means or how to fix. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: You need parenthesis after `ToArray`. Thats the first problem. It should be `ToArray()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To call a method in C#, you need to use parentheses, like this: `test = coordinates.ToArray();`

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the parenthesis:

```
double[][]test = coordinates.ToArray();
```